# Translation of "unerreichbar entfernt"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, german-to-english, french

I want to translate the following phrase from German to English/ French:

> aber *unerreichbar entfernt* durch eine zehn Fuß starke Mauer
>   
>   <sub>([Günther Anders: *Die molussische Katakombe*, p. 17](https://books.google.de/books?id=LMZZRWDiJlUC&pg=PA17&dq=%22aber%20unerreichbar%20entfernt%20durch%20eine%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj97tKyvazpAhVLPJoKHZEAC9EQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22aber%20unerreichbar%20entfernt%20durch%20eine%22&f=false))</sub>

I infer that *unerreichbar* is adverbial and qualifies the other adverb *entfert*.

> → but not to be reach, at distance through a ten feet thick wall

I find no equivalent to translate *unerreichbar entfernt* together. I have to separate and juxtapose the two qualifications, first *not reachable*, then *at distance*. *At distance* could be thought to be implied by the *ten feet* thickness of the wall.

Would you confirm that *unerreichbar* qualifies *entfernt*? Or do you have a better explanation?

Comment: To me, "entfernt durch eine fünf Fuß Mauer" does not make sense.

Comment: @CarstenS, according to the source, that was a typo.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your are on the right track.

In the example phrase, *unerreichbar* is an adverb, which can be translated to English as *unreachably* (notice the adverb ending *-ly*). It specifies the adjective *entfernt*, which can be translated to English as *far* or *distanced*. Put together, this becomes:

> nicht mehr als zehn Fuß über uns, aber *unerreichbar entfernt* durch eine zehn Fuß starke Mauer
>   
>   <sub>([Günther Anders: *Die molussische Katakombe*, p. 17](https://books.google.de/books?id=LMZZRWDiJlUC&pg=PA17&dq=%22aber%20unerreichbar%20entfernt%20durch%20eine%22&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj97tKyvazpAhVLPJoKHZEAC9EQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%22aber%20unerreichbar%20entfernt%20durch%20eine%22&f=false))</sub>
>
> → not more than ten feet obove us, but *unreachably far* by a wall ten feet thick

Comment: thanks, i actually translate to french were there is no common equivalent to unreachably i think. any french translation ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't speak French. But maybe someone else?

Answer (score 2):

How about "but unreachabley distanced by a five foot wall".

Comment: This doesn't feel like an idiomatic translation.

Comment: I agree, but would dare to argue that the German version is also not exactly idiomatic.

Comment: A more idiomatic translation might be "out of reach due to a ten feet thick wall"

Answer (score 0):

this "entfernt" seems not to qualify the distance (in miles), but it stands for the same as "unerreichbar". I think this is a literarical trick. In English it would be "very very unreachable".